# PostgreSQL Storing Large Json Strings (How to Best Optimize for Memory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have three tables, each with an attribute storing large JSON strings as text on a PostgreSQL database (on an AWS RDS instance). These JSON fields represent fabric.js javascript objects for canvas drawing and manipulation. Many of them have svg representations of complex shapes, such as maps.

[image: memory breakdown of tables with large json fields]

My initial assumption was that we could somehow compress these fields whenever writing to the DB, and decompress them whenever we need the JSON. I naively wrote a script for the conversion, using a bytea column type, and zlib compression. I chose select records (using Rails ActiveRecord) to compare the JSON bytesize with the bytesize of the compressed JSON, confirming that the compressed version was usually about half the bytesize. I wanted proof of concept that compressing the JSON attribute on one table (notebook_question_answers) would save some memory.

After running my script on all the records for one table, I was very surprised to find out that compressing the JSON fields and converting them to binary type resulted in ADDED memory usage to the database.

[image: after zlib compression of JSON attribute with binary data type]

So I have two questions:

1. Does the bytea data type have additional overhead? There are many NULL values on this particular DB attribute, and at least 1-4bytes is allocated for each binary data entry. I read on the PostgreSQL that text is optimized for text, so you should use the text datatype. Otherwise, why is there added memory when using compression?
2. I've started to read about json vs jsonb PostgreSQL datatypes. json offers parsing, and jsonb offers optimized indexing for search, as far as I understand. Would one of these be good paths to take for reducing memory consumption when storing large JSON strings? What would you suggest?

EDIT:
The column in question was originally of data type "text", and changed it to bytea.

after running the following command, I now see that the table takes up less space than before. About ~30% reduction of total bytes.

VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, FULL) notebook_question_answers;

[image: after garbage collection]

Comment: Could you provide the *table* definitions in both cases? By `binary`, do you mean [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)?

Comment: Second question: did you perform in both cases a [`VACUUM FULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-vacuum.html) before checking table size?

Comment: Looks like your question is answered: Only `VACUUM FULL` reduces the space. You don't see a bigger improvement because PostgreSQL automatically compresses larke `text` values anyway - see the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) documentation.